# Order of a permutation with one cycle

Tags: group-theory

Say you were given a permutation with one cycle of length $6,$ how could you find the order of this permutation? I know if you use ${\rm lcm}$ if you have two cycles but how can you find the order if the permutation only has one cycle?

Comment: Hint: I think you're overthinking this...

Comment: @Arthur I think I am too, is the order just the length of the single cycle?

Comment: Yup. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Arthur thank you so much! I knew I had to be over thinking it I just wanted to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise the comments into an answer, you were indeed overthinking. The order of a cycle is its length.

Besides, ${\rm lcm}(n, n)=n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. (But see Arthur's "nitpick" below!)

Comment: Theoretical nit-pick: Using $\operatorname{lcm}(n,n)$ like that makes it look more like you are trying to find the order of the product of two disjoint length-$n$ cycles, and that's not what's happening in this problem. If one is intent on using $\operatorname{lcm}$, then I would personally prefer to see it as something that operates not on two integers, but on any _finite set of integers_. And then we have $\operatorname{lcm}(\{n\}) = n$ (or maybe just $\operatorname{lcm}(n) = n$ for short). This also has the bonus of generalizing more nicely for more than two disjoint cycles.